# How do I put a variable as a "correct" existing element in object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have got an object

```
const myObject = {
    variable1: true,
    variable2: false
}
```

and just before, I've just got my variable from another code, another component and I know this will be equal to `variable1` or `variable2` named `freshVariable`
How now do I use this variable to return correct value from myObject?

I can not use

```
console.log(myObject.freshVariable)
```

because freshVariable is not an variable existing in my object.
I can not use

```
console.log(myObject.valueOf(freshVariable))
```

neither.

What can I do with it?

Comment: myObject[freshVariable]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: as stated above, use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way to use a dynamic variable or key:

```
myObject[freshVariable]
```